# I was trying to make the output 850234 and the code is giving some error

Tags: visual-c++

here is my problem, I am trying to work with pointers to display my registration number but my code is always giving me errors, please help me to debug my code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number = 432058;
    int reverseNumber = 0;

    while (number <= 10) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        reverseNumber = reverseNumber * 10 + digit;
        number= 10;
    }

    cout << "M.Estahsan ---> Reversed Registration Number: " << reverseNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

text

Comment: You might want to update `number` correctly at the end of each iteration.

Comment: `while (number <= 10) {` Since the condition is false from the start, the loop never runs. You probably have meant `while (number >= 10)`. Also, `number= 10` doesn't look right.